# Long division of $p(x) = x^3 + x^2 + 1 \in Z_2[x]$ by $(x-\alpha)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I need to find the splitting field of the polynomial $p(x) = x^3 + x^2 + 1 \in Z_2[x]$; Since the polynomial has not roots in $Z_2$, it's irreducible.
Let $\alpha$ a root in a field extension $Z_2(\alpha)$, then $p(x) = (x-\alpha)g(x)$ where $g(x) \in Z_2(\alpha)$. I'd like to perform the long division in $Z_2(\alpha)$, of $p(x)$ by $(x-\alpha)$ in order to find $g(x)$ and eventually find all three roots of the polynomial $p(x)$. I'm able to perform the long division in $Z_2(x)$ but I'm not sure how to do it in $Z_2(\alpha)$. I know there are other methods (like Frobenius) to find the roots but I'd like to employ long division for this problem.

I've also calculated the field $Z_2[x]/((p(x)) ≃ ℤ_2(\alpha)$ which has 8 elements $\{0, 1, 1+\alpha, \alpha^2, 1 + \alpha^2, \alpha + \alpha^2, 1 + \alpha + \alpha^2, \alpha | \alpha^3 + \alpha^2 + 1 = 0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

No long division required.

The polynomial is irreducible, has degree 3 and has $\alpha$ as a root.

By the Frobenius automorphism, the roots are $\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^4$ and they lie in $G(2^3)$.

No long division at all. This formalism is even more powerful:

$x^{2^3}-x$ decomposes into the irreducible polynomials $x,x+1,x^3+x^2+1,x^3+x+1$.

If $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3+x^2+1$, then

$x$ has root $0$, $x+1$ has root $1$, $x^3+x^2+1$ has roots $\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^4$, and $x^3+x+1$ (which is conjugate to $x^3+x^2+1$) has roots $\alpha^3,\alpha^6,\alpha^5$.

Comment: You may need long division to reduce $\alpha^4$ to a linear combination of $1,\alpha,\alpha^2$. Or just notice that $\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^4=-1$.

Comment: My text doesn't introduce the Frobenius automorphism,. I know only that if $p(x) \in F[x]$ isan irreducible polynomial, \alpha and \beta two roots then $F(\alpha) \approx F(\beta)$